# How to pass functions as arguments from Dart/Flutter to Android native code?

Tags: java, android, dart, flutter

I'd like to create a Java-based SDK that can be invoked from Flutter, the Flutter side needs to plug into the SDK by providing callbacks to be executed at different stages of the processing, ideally something like:

```
Future<Result> = doPayment(
  amount: 100.00, 
  currency: 'USD', 
  onPasscodeEntry: () => _renderInputBox(), 
  onValidation: () => _doValidation()
);
```

the processing itself takes some time etc so a `Future<PaymentResult>` pattern makes sense, the application should react to some points of the processing, so it makes sense to pass in callbacks.

Problems:

1. how to pass functions to Java code? [As far as I can tell all the Java-passable method arguments in Flutter are serializable-ish objects](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/platform/android/io/flutter/plugin/common/MethodCall.java#L66)
2. (less critical/optional) how to return a POJO and handle it in Dart? Judging from [the specs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/StandardMessageCodec-class.html) I should encode (within Java) the result in a `ArrayList`/`HashMap` or as a `JSON` string and then create the equivalent constructor in Dart that takes in `List`/`Map` ? This seems a bit unwieldy, so I'm asking if there's a simpler way, preferably without maintaining a Java & Dart variants of the same object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not pass a function.

You can create a map from a function name to a function reference and then pass the function name and look up the function in by name in the map and call it.

You also can't pass a POJO.

You need to serialize it to JSON (or some other supported format) and deserialize it on the other side of the channel. For that you need to have to POJO class implemented in Dart and in Java.

Packages like protobuf or flatbuffer allow to geneerate code for different languages based on an reduced language to specify the data structure.

Comment: I suspected something like that, but that's quite a bummer for anyone wanting to use native SDKs

Comment: I don't think that prevents you from building anything. Some things become a bit cumbersome.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement closures without closures/anonymous functions/classes, and without it a simple SDK where the implementor doesn't worry about the internal workflow of the SDK turns into a complex SDK in which the implementor needs to know all kinds of stuff about what happens inside the SDK, at which point making a simple dart application around it becomes not so simple - and really I'd have to make a separate SDK just for this one Dart app, so it pays off better to go down Kotlin or even pure Java route. It's a shame, I love Dart and I expected a greater level of integration.

Comment: Yes, some things can become complex. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7053 which is currently being worked on will help in some scenarios where C libs are used instead of Java libs.