# How is Dart Isolate implemented in Flutter for Android/ iOS?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I have a problem understanding Dart Isolates and how they are implemented in Flutter for Android/ iOS. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54389021/14434426) states that "Dart is compiled to native machine code (ARM, Intel, ...) executable and bundled with some native platform code (Java, Kotlin, Objective-C/Swift) to interact with the native platform."

When I use a Dart Isolate in Flutter, e.g. for Android, is the Isolate compiled to something like [Workmanager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager), or does it "only" use the Dart Isolate itself?

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is a high level implementation of things, you don't need to think on processor level, system process level it is all handled by Target OS,

On low level a Thread is a light-weight process that performs some task and uses system resources like CPU,

As per ISOLATE specification

***Each Dart isolate has a single thread of execution and shares no mutable objects with other isolates.***

Using Isolate you create a separate thread that handles the separate task without intercepting the main thread of your dart/flutter App,