# How to set up a publish-subscribe channel between a Flutter app and it's android/ios code?

Tags: java, android, dart, flutter

So, we have `MethodChannel` that's covered in the [Writing custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) document section that sends a single request to Javaland and returns a single response, but what I'd like to do is set up a literal pubsub channel between services running on Android & my flutter app, this would allow an alternative approach to [my earlier question about passing closures as arguments to Java-side](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54365439/1983072) since it would allow the function

```
Future<Result> = doPayment(
  amount: 100.00, 
  currency: 'USD', 
  onPasscodeEntry: () => _renderInputBox(), 
  onValidation: () => _doValidation()
);
```

to be implemented by doing something like:

```
Future<Result> doPayment({int amount, String currency, Function onPasscodeEntry, Function onValidation}) {
    Subscription sub;
    try {
        sub = subscribe(channel: 'myapp/doPayment/$paymentUid')
        sub.send("initialize", {"amount": amount, "currency": currency});

        sub.receive("onPasscodeEntry").then((payload) => onPasscodeEntry(payload));
        sub.receive("onValidation").then((payload) => onValidation(payload));

        return sub.receive("result")
    finally {
        sub?.send("deinitialize");
        sub?.end()
        return null;
    }
}
```

You get the idea :-)

It *seems* like [BasicMessageChannel](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/BasicMessageChannel-class.html) could be my friend, but there's no usage example, and there's no samples on how to hook into it on the platform-side (aka Javaland), and I'd expect a receive function too - something that waits on something happening in Javaland and pushing a notification to Flutter-side,

a simple example of this would be if the `MethodChannel` usage example had the ability to push battery status updates into flutter, and not just fetch them from flutter on demand.

It's not specifically necessary for the above example, but I'd like to set up a 2-way communication channel with the platform - for what I'm doing I just need to know at this point that this door is not closed to me if I go for Flutter.

I'm looking for the right classes/libraries to use flutter-side and java-side and code samples since that part is not really very well covered in the docs.

Comment: You can use it like this: `val channel = BasicMessageChannel(activity.flutterView, appChannel, StringCodec.INSTANCE);
        channel.send(message);` where `activity` is instance of `FlutterActivity`, `appChannel` is app channel name string, and `message` is your string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is currently possible using a combination of `MethodChannel` & `EventChannel` - one messages from Flutter to platform, one from platform to Flutter (once Flutter-side subscribes) - as demonstrated in the [example on Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/platform_channel) (there's also a separate [example for swift](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/platform_channel_swift)).

Technically this means a pub-sub can be implemented, it's just not nice to do it, [I wrote an issue about it to Flutter's team](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27232) - suggesting a `Stream`-based API instead (and then you can leverage `rxdart`, `rxjava`, `rxswift` & others), so we'll see how it goes.